# How to change maxlength of certain element using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following element:

```
<input name="someelement" title="Title" class="someclass" id="someid" maxlength="255" value="Some Value" />
```

I want to change its length to 100. Can I do something like?

```
document.getElementById("someid").maxlength = 100;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('input[name="someelement"]').attr('maxlength', 100);
```

or

```
$('input.someclass').attr('maxlength', 100);
```

or like tanaydin said :

```
$('#someid').attr('maxlength', 100);
```

Comment: also

    $('#someid').attr('maxlength', 100);

could be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

**Using JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("someid").setAttribute("maxlength", 100);
```

or

```
document.getElementById("someid").maxLength = 100;
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
$('#someid').attr('maxlength', 100);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *javascript* `maxLength` property

```
document.getElementById("someid").maxLength = 100;
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Answer (score 0):

To answer second part of your question:

*Javascript*:

```
document.getElementById("someid").maxLength = "100";
```

*JQuery*:

```
$('#someid').attr('maxlength', 100);
```

**Note**:

1. It is `maxLength` (uppercase L).
2. The value better be provided as string (in quotes) although the attribute itself is implemented as Long.